# Common Mode Noise filtering for Diff Mode Circuit

Tags: filter, noise, emc

I have a circuit that has only two pins, and there is no earth ground.

However, I have to test it for BCI and design a common-mode filter with diff mode.

Designing a diff mode filter is simple but common-mode without earth ground is very complicated, or it is for me. The circuit has a buck converter and the frequency is 250 kHz. What kind of filter should I design?

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT0ame.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could you post an image of the pcb layout? Depending on the filter placement on the board you may have some parasitic capacitance from the input lines directly to your SMPS (or to the 0V reference plane), partly bypassing the common mode choke.

Answer (score 1):

How is the design to be placed relative to the ground plane used during testing? This is very important.

If you don’t know, you will need to find out because, how it is placed will influence what nodes on your “apparently purely differential and floating circuit” might have unwanted capacitive interactions with ground that produce (or create) common mode noise.

Whether those common mode noise levels are sufficient to contravene the regulations you wish your circuit to be compliant with is another matter. For this you need to investigate more and then (and only then) should you decide what measures you might need to apply.

But, there are some things you can do beforehand. For instance, if your perfectly differential circuit was encased in a metal case and that metal case were grounded to the 0 volts of your wires (in and out presumably) then you can begin to pre-think about measures that can be taken.

This is because there is no physical orientation of the encased circuit that now makes the production of common mode noise any worse when considered against a ground plane. But there is a cost!

Comment: The earth ground and 0V of supply are short circuits before LISN, you can show test setup https://www.ahsystems.com/notes/bulk-current-injection-test.php.

Comment: What part of that document tells you about the common mode filter?

Comment: That document tells the test setup for BCI. The standard is confidential, sorry I can't publish it.

Comment: Also, the case of the product is plastic and have no ground, I see other products passed this test without earth ground a choke and two capacities. In my application, SMPS is reset and the product fails the test, I think it is due to the wrong filter design.

Comment: You haven’t disclosed the filter design so what is *the wrong filter design*?

Comment: added the schematic, can't make common mode filter, I know it's differential mode filter because the current returns to supply.

Comment: Given that it is a susceptibility problem and your circuit is intentionally balanced and floating then maybe it’s not as balanced capacitively as you might think. To investigate you need to review what nodes of your circuit might be susceptible. However there’s only so much that can be given remotely but you ought to consider posting a circuit and layout. You cant design a filter to avoid problems when you don’t know what caused the problem.